# Embedding varieties as divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

1. Let $X$ be a smooth affine algebraic variety. Does there necessarily exist an embedding into some affine space $A^n$ of codimension $1$?

I guess so. Next one I'm less sure.

2. Let $X$ be a complete intersection inside an affine space $A^m$. Does there exist a different embedding into another $A^n$ of codimension $1$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every smooth affine curve can be embedded into the affine plane so the answer is no.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel stupid. Could you just give me an example of such a curve? Thanks so mcuh.

Comment: A smooth curve embedded into $\mathbb{A}^2$ has trivial canonical bundle. Take any smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $\geq 2$ and general point $p\in C$, then $C\smallsetminus p$ is affine with non-trivial canonical bundle.

Comment: @abx Of course, thanks!!

Comment: @abx Could you explain why the canonical bundle being nontrivial on $C$ globally implies that it is nontrivial on $C \smallsetminus p$ for a general $p$?

Comment: @user2831784: from the exact sequence of Picard groups for $C \setminus p \subset C$ one gets that if $K_{C \setminus p}$ is trivial, then $K = (2g-2)[p]$. This can not hold for general $p$, as if it does for points $p$ and $q$, then $[p] - [q]$ is $(2g-2)$-torsion in the Jacobian.